# Installing OpenCV on Raspbian Buster

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, opencv

I'm trying to install OpenCV on Raspbian Buster. I've followed a guide but when I try to import cv2 in Python 3.8.0 it says No module named 'cv2'. Python 3.8.0 is set to my default Python installation, but when I navigate to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, that's where I see the cv2 module. It is also installed under python3.7, but not under 3.8. Is there a way I can use it with Python 3.8?

EDIT: I seem to have fixed it by creating a symbolic link between the Python3.8 and 3.7 site-packages folder.

Comment: How did you install opencv?

Answer (score 0):

You can install current `opencv` for python3 with `sudo pip3 install opencv-python`. Note the use of `pip3` to install for `python3`.

Comment: Didn't work for me, pretty sure its because I'm on Raspbian Buster and so I had to manually install it. Though, I seem to have fixed it by creating a symbolic link in the Python3.8 site-packages folder to the Python3.7 packages folder.